# Extracting info out of a table from external html

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am writing a GM script to scrap info off a web page which contains a table (there is only 1 table in and with no id.) and append the some information from that table into a existing webpage. I have gotten everything to work except of extracting the information from the file that i gotten from `GM_xmlhttprequest`.

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: 'GET',
  url: tableToBeScrape,
  onload: function (response) {
    var respDoc = response.responseText;
    console.log(respDoc);
    alert(respDoc);
  }
});
```

The respDoc returns the webpage in the full HTML form. But I had difficulty extracting the info out. I had tried a few ways

```
var listAllArray = [];
responseHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.responseText, 'text/html');
listAllArray = responseHTML.getElementsByClassName('table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed');
```

Using a for loop and loop thru the `listAllArray` I got nothing out of the array.

Here is how the html looks like

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Part ID</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
            ...
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ...
            <td>123</td>
            <td>sn123456</td>
            ...
            <td>shelf 12</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I extract the Part ID, Serial Number and Location out of the table?

Part 2: 
The response I gotten from `response.responseText` was different from what I assumed. There was no table but rather `div ul li`.

```
<div class='search_refinements' data-collapsed='true'     data-role='collapsible'>
<h4>Refine Your Results</h4>
<ul data-filter='true' data-role='listview'>
<li data-role='list-divider'>Company Name</li>
<li> ACB Inc. </li>
...
<li data-role='list-divider'>Part</li>
<li> 123 </li>
<li data-role='list-divider'>Serial Number</li>
<li> sn123456</li>
...
<li data-role='list-divider'>Location</li>
<li> shelf 12</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have tagged `jQuery`

you can just parse it and create a DOM element and find whatever you need.

```
var tableDom = $(response.responseText);
var th = tableDom.find('th');
var td = tableDom.find('td');
```

now iterate `td` and fetch the `text()` of all jQuery object, or `innerText` of the all raw DOM object

```
var data = {};
td.each(function(item,idx){
    data[th[idx].innerText] = item.innerText;
});
```

now you can get the value for the column you want just by using

```
data["some column name"];
```

Comment: the `td.each(function(item,idx)` is not looping thru, when i do a console.log for both th and td it do return an object

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using jQuery,

You can do this,

```
var table = $(response.responseText).find("table").find("tbody");

var rows = table.find('tr');
rows.each(function(index, row){
    var columns = $(row).find('td');
    var partId = columns.eq(0).html();
    var serialNumber = columns.eq(1).html();
    var location = columns.eq(2).html();

    console.log("Part Id : " + partId);
    console.log("Serial Number : " + serialNumber);
    console.log("Location : " + location);
});
```

Comment: `rows.each(function(index, row)` is not looping thru, `rows` did return an object when i did a console.log, I put a `console.log(row);` but it is not returning anything, no error, nothing

Comment: am I encountering the async nature of xmlhttpRequest which the object is populated after therefore the loop is empty and causing it not to loop?

Comment: Hi @LHH, sorry for the late response. In my  understanding, if "response.responseText" is able to return the HTML string, then above code will work given that the table structure you posted is same as returned table structure.

Comment: @LHH, maybe try to post the whole content of "response.responseText".

Comment: sorry for the late reply, was away for a few days, you are right the content returned by "response.responseText" was indeed different, I will update the question and show the "response.responseText"